# How to connect to Amazon Keyspaces using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-keyspaces

I'm trying to connect to Amazon Keyspaces leveraging the `Assume role provider` which refreshes the credentials the moment they expire. I've set up my aws config file as the documentation states

```
[profile cassandra]
role_arn=role_to_assume
source_profile=default
role_session_name=testingCassandraConnection
duration_seconds=900
```

then, within the code I start a session with that profile

```
boto_session = boto3.Session(profile_name='cassandra', region_name='us-east-1')
auth_provider = SigV4AuthProvider(boto_session) 

cluster = Cluster(
    [CASSANDRA_CLUSTER],
    ssl_context=ssl_context,
    auth_provider=auth_provider,
    port=9142
)

session = cluster.connect()
```

but I get the error `Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Authentication failure: SessionId mismatch`

I  also tried using `sts_client.assume_role` and passing the credentials directly to `boto3.Session()` and it works this way but I won't be able to refresh credentials when they expire.

has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: Ah! So you're saying it works fine with an IAM User, but fails when an IAM Role is provided in the AWS CLI profile. I think that the ability for the AWS CLI to assume a role from a profile is limited to the AWS CLI and is not used by boto3 or any other AWS SDK. However, I note that the [SigV4 authentication plugin for the open-source Python Driver for Apache Cassandra. Allows use of IAM users and roles.](https://github.com/aws/aws-sigv4-auth-cassandra-python-driver-plugin) _does_ mention the use of **Roles**. I suggest you **log an issue** on that GitHub project and see what they say.

Comment: thank you @JohnRotenstein I didn't know that the profiles from the config file were limited to the AWS CLI, I already posted what worked for me if you want to take a look. Cheers

Comment: The profiles are used by the AWS SDKs, but I believe the ability to **automatically assume a role from a profile** is a feature of the AWS CLI only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it, turns out that the `botocore` library has a way to deal with refreshable credentials.

```
def assumed_role_session(role_arn: str,
                         base_session: botocore.session.Session = None):
    # Default session
    base_session = base_session or boto3.session.Session()._session

    fetcher = botocore.credentials.AssumeRoleCredentialFetcher(
        client_creator=base_session.create_client,
        source_credentials=base_session.get_credentials(),
        role_arn=role_arn,
        extra_args={
            # set this if you want something non-default
            # 'RoleSessionName': None
            # 'DurationSeconds': 3600
        }
    )

    creds = botocore.credentials.DeferredRefreshableCredentials(
        method='assume-role',
        refresh_using=fetcher.fetch_credentials,
        time_fetcher=lambda: datetime.datetime.now(tzlocal())
    )

    botocore_session = botocore.session.Session()
    botocore_session._credentials = creds

    return boto3.Session(botocore_session=botocore_session)
```

first of all we need to pass the info for a client to be created with `fetcher`, we then use that fetcher object to specify how the credentials are going to be refreshed in `creds`, finally, a boto3 session is returned with the `botocore` session (this session already has the rotating credentials set) as a base.

This returned session is then passed to the auth provider as follows:

`auth_provider = SigV4AuthProvider(session)`

and it works.

function taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171849/aws-boto3-assumerole-example-which-includes-role-usage)

full botocore.credentials documentation [here](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/fdaafc09aecf86cd6c9fb96d4c251d909073877c/botocore/credentials.py#L268)