# Count the number of EC2 instances cross-account

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I need to create a python lambda function which check a set of conditions.
One of the is to count the number of running ec2 instances with a specific name from another aws account.

I searched stackoverflow and found something like this, but this should only count the instances from the same account/region.

```
def ec2(event, context):
ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
instances = [instance.state['Name'] for instance in ec2_resource.instances.all()]
ec2_running_instances = instances.count('running')
print(ec2_running_instances)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS: Boto3: AssumeRole example which includes role usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171849/aws-boto3-assumerole-example-which-includes-role-usage)

Comment: You need to assume a role in the target account prior to running the actual ec2 commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this directly from your account. You must assume IAM role that is created in the second account, with permissions to describe the instances. Please check: [Delegate access across AWS accounts using IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) .

Once the role exists, you have to use boto3's [assume_role](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role) to assume the role, get **temporary aws credentials**, and then create new [boto3 session](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html) with that credentials.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Would it be easier and better to just create a user and access keys in my account, instead of always generating temporary credentials?

Sorry if it's a stupid question, but i'm not experienced in AWS

Comment: Hello Marcin, i have one more question. I want to access from my python lambda function using boto3 more then one resource type. I need to access EC2 to describe instance, SQS to check queue attribute, and to send data to an SNS Topic. Do i need to get the temporary credentials for every aws recource? Or are the credentials available for the whole boto3 session?

Comment: Im reffering to this part of code 

`# Use the temporary credentials that AssumeRole returns to make a connection to Amazon EC2
ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2',
                              aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
                              aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
                              aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
                              )`