# How to restart bucket listing with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to list the content of a very large S3 bucket. I do so in the following way

```
    import boto3        
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts', aws_access_key_id='***', aws_secret_access_key='***')

    assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(    RoleArn="***", RoleSessionName="***" )

    credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']

    s3_resource = boto3.resource(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
    )



    my_bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
```

Then I list the content as follows:

```
all_content = []
for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
   print( len(all_content), my_bucket_object.key)
   all_content = all_content + [{'key':my_bucket_object.key, 'size':my_bucket_object.size}]enter code here
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that my credentials are no longer valid before the listing is complete.

Is there some way to have the objects.all() function skip the first N objects, so that I can run again and append new items? Or is there some other thing I can do to restart this process where it left off?

Comment: Have you considered using `sts_client.assume_role(..., DurationSeconds=43200)`? That can provide up to 12 hours of validity.

Comment: While what you ask directly might be possible, it would be much easier if you use a [refreshable session object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45834847) so that the underlying APIs can refresh the necessary tokens as needed.

Comment: @AnonCoward Wow, I've never seen that before. Also looks to be undocumented (unless you look at the boto3 source code!). Nice.

Comment: Are you saying that your code is simply compiling a list of Keys and Sizes, and it times-out? The default timeout is 3600 seconds (1 hour) -- does it take more than an hour for your code to run? If you have a HUGE number of objects in the bucket, you could instead use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.